# Using result in the outer query in the inner query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

What I'm trying to do is to query all the unique district name from the database, and on each district name, get its corresponding `MIN` and `MAX` `ID`.

Here's what I have right now:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DISTRICTNAME, 
(SELECT MIN(`ID`)
    FROM [DATABASE_NAME]
        WHERE DISTRICTNAME = DISTRICTNAME) AS 'MIN', 
(SELECT MAX(`ID`) 
    FROM [DATABASE_NAME]
        WHERE DISTRICTNAME = DISTRICTNAME) AS 'MAX'
FROM [DATABASE_NAME]
WHERE [CONDITION]
ORDER BY DISTRICTNAME;
```

Problem: The `MIN` and `MAX` column shows the same value. I'm not really sure about my inner query's `WHERE` clause. I think that's the problem.

Help?

Comment: You have to specify the outer DISTRICTNAME in the sub-quries' conditions. Also, are you really using MySQL here, with square brackets for delimited identifiers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query with `GROUP BY`clause

```
SELECT DISTRICTNAME, MIN(`ID`) AS 'MIN', MAX(`ID`) AS 'MAX'
FROM [DATABASE_NAME]
WHERE [CONDITION]
GROUP BY DISTRICTNAME
ORDER BY DISTRICTNAME;;
```